# Difference between la vs ls -a command?

Tags: command-line, ls

There is a slightly difference between when comparing those commands.

Answer (score 4):

If I type`alias` I get

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/de2900/lubuntu_64$   alias
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

which shows how the `la` command is interpreted.  `ls` does not include the '-A' parameter.

from `man ls`

> -a, --all
> do not ignore entries starting with .
>
> -A, --almost-all
> do not list implied . and ..

Comment: Note:  My `alias` results may differ to yours, this system has been upgraded over seven cycles, so has no doubt had lots of changes...

Comment: No worries!  +1 to you my friend!